# Why won't Groovy print runtime arguments?

Tags: command-line, groovy

My Groovy app:

```
class Driver {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        println "Arg0 is: " + args[0]
    }
}
```

When I run the following command:

> java -jar -DshouldPrint=yes myapp.jar

I get:

> Arg0 is: [Ljava.lang.String;@a7e666

Why won't groovy show me the value of my runtime args?

Comment: What you pass is not an argument but a System property. It can be obtained via `System.properties`. Argument should be passed as follows: `java -jar myapp.jar here1 here2 here3`.

Comment: Thanks @Opal (+1) - so to use your example should my invocation be `java -jar myapp.jar shouldPrint=yes` or `java -jar myapp.jar shouldPrint yes`?

Comment: It seems so. `shouldPrint=yes` will be a single entry on `args` list.

Comment: Let me know it if worked. I'll add an answer to be accepted.

Comment: also consider using http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html - it makes your live and the live of your users easier.

Comment: and as a random side note: i doubt, that above code would give that output.  the output looks like `println "Arg0 is: " + args`.  `args[0]` without params would throw.

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys, adding an answer then, please accept.

Comment: @cfrick, you're absolutely right with both side notes :)

Answer (score 0):

What you pass is not an argument but a *system property* (`-D`). It can be obtained via `System.properties`. Arguments should be passed as follows:

```
java -jar myapp.jar here1 here2 here3
```

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys if that answer along with the comments helped you, please accept it.